# Select result set into a variable, and then use that variable in an update later in the same stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Okay, so this is either not possible, or I suck at Googling. (the latter being the more likely here)
My question is this: Using stored procedures, is it possible to select a result set of ids into a variable, and then use those ids as the condition for an `IN` in an update that runs in the same SP?
I'm going for something like this (I recognize I'm ignoring delimiter conflicts here)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
DECLARE var1 INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT id INTO var1 FROM table WHERE this='this';
some other stuff
UPDATE table2 SET blah='blah' WHERE fk_id IN (var1);
END;
```

"some other stuff" basically manipulates data in such a way that I wont be able to get the appropriate list of ids by using an inner query inside the `IN`, so I basically need to "save" the appropriate list of ids into a variable and then use that variable later.  Can this be done?

Please don't suggest other ways of doing this/restructuring my data/logic so I don't have to worry about this. All I need to know is if/how this can be done.  I have backup options if it can't be done, this would just be the most preferable way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp AS (SELECT id FROM table WHERE this='this');
some other stuff
UPDATE table2 SET blah='blah' WHERE fk_id IN (SELECT id FROM tmp);
END;
```

Comment: ah okay. so from what I'm seeing around the web, it seems like the only way to really "carry over" result sets with multiple rows from one query to another is to use temp tables. Is that the case? If so, I'll accept the answer, otherwise if it can be accomplished without using temp tables, that would be better.