# loop to Select a record value into variable then CONCAT a value onto first variable and then update that record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Trying to update a SQL value with a concatenated value. Example, existing table has column named PONumber. Some numbers are stored by users as 4444 and some are stored as 4444.00. We want to update all the numbers listed as 4444 with the appended .00.  I have the variables worked out and the concatenate worked out and binding the two together. I am just lost on the loop of getting and then updating it back. I am assuming I need a temp table for this or can I just use a set of variables for the old number, appending value, and new number?

```
DECLARE @ponumb nvarchar(255)

DECLARE @append nvarchar(255) = '-00'

DECLARE @BIND nvarchar(255) = CONCAT (@ponumb, @append) 

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cache (SELECT @ponumb = PONumber FROM TABLE1 where PONumber not like '%-00%');


UPDATE TABLE1 SET PONumber=@BIND WHERE PONumber IN (SELECT PONumber FROM cache);

END;
```

Need to update the PONumbers to all have a trailing -00

Comment: I've looked at this one and it doesnt really cover my issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23663707/select-result-set-into-a-variable-and-then-use-that-variable-in-an-update-later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want to do?

```
UPDATE TABLE1
    SET PONumber = PONumber + '.00'
    WHERE PONumber NOT LIKE '%.00';
```

Comment: That might be it! What happens if it returns more than one record? would it update that specific POnumber with just the trailing .00?! \

Comment: I created two test records and set the where clause to target them and it updated them perfectly! Wow, that was stupid easy.
`WHERE PONumber = '911911' or PONumber = '922922' `  Thanks for the help!!